# Trouble understanding authmodes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm trying to create a Google Sheets add-on that runs in a sidebar. This is my first and I'm having a hard time working through the Auth modes.

[This is the doc I'm using to reference.](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle?hl=pt-br)

When someone in my org installs the script, they see the menu title, but the add-on fails to load the menu items. The logging shows that `Exception: You do not have permission to call getScriptProperties at ...`. This is from a library that I wrote and am referencing in my script. When they use it on a doc where I've used it before, they're able to see the menu items.

Based on this chart, it looks like that user is in AuthMode.NONE since they cannot access Properties.

[image]

This is the code that I have at the top of my file.

```
function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
    console.info('onOpen(e) fired')
    var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.

    if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
        console.info("(e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE)")
        // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
        menu.addItem("Show Sidebar", "showSidebar");
        menu.addToUi();
    } else {
        // Add a new menu (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
        log("not (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE)")
        var topUI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        topUI.createMenu("Test Set Creator")
            .addItem("Show Sidebar", "showSidebar")
            .addToUi();
    }
    console.info(`The user is ${e.user}`)
    console.info(`The user's auth mode is ${e.authMode}`)
    console.info(`The source is ${e.source}`)
}
```

So essentially, I want a user to install the add-on and then be able to use it on any spreadsheet they want in the org's domain, not just where it's been used before. I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around how the different Auth Modes work and how they change per user/per sheet. If the user has to authorize the add on when they install it, why wouldn't they have access to the add on in a new spreadsheet they open?

Here are some other resources I've tried to use:
[Google Doc onOpen will not fire when spreadsheet is accessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202310/google-doc-onopen-will-not-fire-when-spreadsheet-is-accessed)

Answer (score 0):

### Considerations

1. Published Add-Ons will append menu items to the corresponding addon menu automatically:

> Caution: Unpublished add-ons can also create custom top-level menus, but these are automatically moved under the Add-ons menu if the add-on is published and may not result in the user experience you intended. If you intend to publish the add-on, always use Ui.createAddonMenu() to define the add-on menu.

2. `onOpen()` function is designed to run in `AuthMode.NONE` the first time for every document. If you already authorized the Add On on another document, opening a new document won't prompt you for authorization again. However, it won't allow you to run the first `onOpen()` function in `AuthMode.LIMITED`. This means that you should always trigger auth requiring operations by Add On menu items.

Keep in mind that the second time you open your document the `onOpen()` function will run in `AuthMode.LIMITED`, this means that refreshing the page will do the trick. That said, if you found a way to trigger the `onOpen()` function again this behavior could be obtained automatically.

My advise here is to create a menu voice in your add-on that basically starts up your add-on functionalities, builds the proper menu items and UIs. In this way you won't create confusion between new users and the ones who already concluded the authorization flow successfully.

### References

[Add-on Menus](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/menus)

[Authorization lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_model)